# How to improve the decoration ends with tikz decorate

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

you will see two problems on the example below

1) how to make the plot line is not under the terminal markings

2) Why is it the text in bold

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={markings,
mark connection node=my node,
mark=at position 0  with {\node [draw,blue,transform shape,inner sep=0,minimum size=1em,fill=white] (my node) {->};},
mark=at position 0.5  with {\arrow{stealth}},
mark=at position 1  with {\node [draw,blue,transform shape,inner sep=0,minimum size=1em,fill=white] (my node) {->};},
},decorate,green](0,0) --(3,1)node[pos=0.5,below,black,text width =5em,align=center]{signal amplifie};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

merci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection node is meant to be connecting so first a path is drawn to the `west` anchor and then path is continued. Anchoring the connection nodes again is innocent enough to hide those zero length paths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={markings,
mark connection node=my node,
mark=at position 0  with {\node [draw,blue,transform shape,inner sep=0,minimum size=1em,fill=white,anchor=east] (my node) {->};},
mark=at position 0.5  with {\arrow{stealth}},
mark=at position 1  with {\node [draw,blue,transform shape,inner sep=0,minimum size=1em,fill=white,anchor=west] (my node) {->};},
},decorate,green](0,0) --(3,1)node[pos=0.5,below,black,text width =5em,align=center]{signal amplifie};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thancks, what about the second pb

Comment: @rpapa The screenshot shows that it is not in bold. If I make it bold it really becomes bold so I can't reproduce that.